# Install xilinx platform usb in Kbuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers

I installed Xilinx programer old version 13.1 on Kununtu 20.04 64 bit.  The USB cable driver did not work.  I tried to follow the instruction to download the USB driver.  It request to complite the source code to make it work but it always give me the problem. after I "sudo make libe32", It always give some error.

I do not know that what can I do.
Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: "it always gives some error" - it'd be useful to know what errors you're seeing and what exactly you're building, where you are getting this 'driver' from, etc.  Right now, there's not enough information to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.